# Create array of a stuct based on user input Swiftui

Tags: arrays, swiftui, multidimensional-array, arraylist, struct

I have a screen for user input.

[image]

[image]

After the user fills in data the next screen appear, but "Number of Stands" tells me how many items are in my array.

[image]

It seems i need an array of an array?  The "Number of Stands" on screen 1 dictates how many items are in array.  i need my struct of "Stand" to display uniquely because in screen 2 i need the user to enter properties of each item in the array so i can perform a equation.  Currently it just duplicates as i understand that but how do i separate each item in array to a self.id to be individual?

[image]

Here is my struct:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Stand: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String {
        return self.stand
    }
    
    var stand: String
    let area: String
    let speed: Int
    var rf: Int
}
```

Here is "Calculate Area screen" Code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

@Observable
class Stands {
    var items = [Stand]()
    
}

struct Speeds1View: View {

    let title: String
    let productArea: String
    let noStands: String
    let billetArea: String
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var standCount: Int {
        let sc = Int(noStands) ?? 0
        return sc
    }
    @State private var standArray = [Stand]()

    @State var txtspeedCurrent: String
    @State private var rF = ""
    @State private var standNo: Int = 0
    @State private var rFCalculated: Int = 0
    @State private var stand = Stands()

    var body: some View {
        let arr = Array(1...standCount)
        NavigationStack{
                ZStack{
                    List{

                        ForEach(arr, id: \.self) { standCount in
                            StandRowView(stand: "\(standCount)", speedCurrent: $txtspeedCurrent, rfactor: "Area1/Area2")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I am sorry to bother anyone on here but if anyone can point me in the right direction on this I would appreciate it.  Thank you.

Comment: Instead of a `standCount` use `yourArray.count`. When the "Number of Stands" `TextField` changes (`onChange` or `task(id:)`) add or remove elements to `yourArray`

Comment: im sorry, but i truly do not understand how to combine standCount to point to yourArray.count.  (standArray.count)

Comment: seems like i need something like "let arr = Array of standArray(1...standCount)".

Comment: There is a better chance of getting a specific answer if you provide an MRE. But add or remove items from the array when the TextField changes.

Comment: im sorry if im not explaining this correctly. When someone enters "5" in textfield i want to product an array of 5 Stands.  I want the id to be 1-5 for each bc ill need to reference each stand for a func later.

Comment: Use onChange or task(id:)

Comment: i added few more photos and tried clearing up my problem.  onChange or task(id:) is what i need once i get these separated i think.  to do further calculations.  Thank you for that tip.